# Correct babel configuration for server-side rendering with React?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, server-side, server-side-rendering

I'm trying server-side rendering for the first time, and I'm stuck simply trying to get Node to run my server file without throwing an error on `<App />`:

```
<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)}</div>
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The only help I've been able to glean from google searches brings up outdated or seemingly bad advice (ex: using babel-node, which is too heavy for production). Can anyone take a peak at my code and give me some suggestions?

https://github.com/gigamesh/aud.io/tree/temporary-demo

Answer (score 0):

In file [server.js](https://github.com/gigamesh/aud.io/blob/temporary-demo/server/server.js), why is the *babel-register* plugin commented out?
It is supposed to handle exactly this issue.
Try uncommenting it, and also add the .tsx extension, like so:

```
require("babel-register")({
   extensions: [".tsx", ".es6", ".es", ".jsx", ".js"],
 });
```

That should fix the problem.

BTW, you can try using the newer [@babel/register](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register).

Comment: I think that's something I tried after seeing it on a forum thread but I still couldn't get it to work. I appreciate the response though. I'll take another look.